# I want to hide all rows in a google drive spreadsheet that do not have any value in the cells in Column A

Tags: google-sheets

I want to hide all rows in a google drive spreadsheet that do not have any value in the cells in Column A.  Then be able to view them again when needed.  What is the script/formula for this function?  Thanks

Comment: As a first recommendation, take a look at [Google Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script), specifically [Spreadsheet Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet), you'll see methods like `DeleteRows(RowPosition, howMany)`, `insertRowsAfter(afterPosition, howMany)`, `hideRow(row)` and `unhideRow(row)` that can be useful.

Comment: Thanks this is partly helpful.  I found this:  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];

 // This hides the first row
 var range = sheet.getRange("A1");
 sheet.hideRow(range);
But I am very new to scripting so what I really need to know if what is the script for hiding rows with no value in column A?  what do I type and where?  thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UPDATED to include a menu to Show all Rows:

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
var range = sheet.getRange(1, 1, sheet.getLastRow());


function onOpen() {
    //add menu called Visibility onOpen
    ss.addMenu("Visibility", [{
        name: "Show All Rows", functionName: "showAllRows"
    }]);

    //get the values to those rows
    var values = range.getValues();

    //go through every row
    for (var i=0; i<values.length; i++){

        //if row value is equal to empty  
        if(values[i][0] === ""){

        //hide that row
        sheet.hideRows(i+1);   
        }   
    }
}

function showAllRows(){
    sheet.showRows(1,sheet.getLastRow());
}
```

Comment: You might have to authorize the script to run. Try running the script from the script editor window.

Comment: Thanks so much Blexy, I got the script to work finally.  Another question for you, is there a way to have a script/action to unhide all the rows in 1 click (rather than selecting each set of hidden rows)?  Thanks

Comment: @user2622970 I've added a menu with an option to show all rows.

Comment: The menu will show up to the right of the Help Menu in the top part of the spreadsheet.

Comment: thanks Blexy!  you're a life-saver.  if you know of any good online videos that I could watch to help me learn and understand more about scripting then please let me know.  these scripts have worked but i would like to know how and why they worked.

Answer (score 0):

I've modified Blexy's menu to allow hiding of empty rows as a menu item rather than doing so during onOpen.

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0]; //Sheet1 is in Array[0]
var range = sheet.getRange(1, 1, sheet.getLastRow());


function onOpen() {
    //add menu called Visibility onOpen
    ss.addMenu("Visibility", 
               [{
                 name: "Show All Rows", functionName: "showAllRows"
                 },
                {
                 name: "Hide All Empty Rows", functionName: "hideAllEmptyRows"
                 }
               ]
              );
}

function showAllRows(){
    sheet.showRows(1,sheet.getLastRow());
}

function hideAllEmptyRows(){
  //get the values to those rows
    var values = range.getValues();

  //go through every row
  for (var i=0; i<values.length; i++){
        //if row value is equal to empty  
        if(values[i][0] === ""){

        //hide that row
        sheet.hideRows(i+1);   
        }   
    }

}
```

Comment: Line 2:
If you prefer to use Sheet Name instead of Sheet Array Number, you can replace line 2 to:
'var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");'